# How can i display a webpage that is on a different domain on a tab in gocd

Tags: go-cd

Is there a plugin or any other way to display an external webpage in a tab in go-cd. Our test results are hosted on a different domain and i would like to show it in gocd.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something similar to what you are looking for: https://docs.go.cd/current/configuration/dev_upload_test_report.html#uploading-a-flash-video-and-displaying-it-as-a-sub-tab

It should be easy to add if you can get the external webpage source as an artifact!

Comment: I am able to get the external source page as an artifact. However because it s external to the gocd domain, page doesnt load in the custom tab , i think due to the default browser security feature to prevent cross domain access. I guess i just have to live with it may be.